# Google Cloud Functions real-time communication to Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I have set up a GCloud Function for HTTP Requests to insert some Data/Files into a CloudSQL Postgres DB and the GCloud Storage. When i'm triggering those function, i want to receive an update about the inserting data to all my Clients (React Frontend in Browser). First, i thought of PubSub, but i couldn't find any documentation for the GCloud API to work on the client side. I think, for a Socket Broadcast the GCloud Function lifecycle is too short.

Is there a way to achieve a real-time connection directly to client-side or do i have to take the indirect way first to a backend (to use PubSub) and then to the Frontend?

Also, a few application do rely on the CLoudSQL Postgres DB, so i can't switch to Firebase or some similar Event Database approach.

Comment: Firebase cloud messaging, what use to be called GoogleCloudMessages would allow you to alert all clients after an action https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ This doesn't require a switch of databases to use just a single feature.

Comment: yea, this could actually work. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment by [@FridayPush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10240790/fridaypush) that answered the question:

Firebase Cloud Messaging, what use to be called GoogleCloudMessages would allow you to alert all clients after an action [firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). This doesn't require a switch of databases to use just a single feature.